# Connecting Live Agent to Custom Dashboard

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

Has anyone had success exporting live queue and agent counts, from Live Agent, to an external dashboard or database?

Specifically looking for, "How many agents are logged in to a queue", "How many customers are queued, waiting for an agent", etc

Ideally, this information would be exposed via the RestAPI, but I'm not finding any documentation for this.

Comment: It turns out, this is possible. However, it's not documented anywhere, as far as I can tell.

If you authenticate against a specific endpoint, the "chat/rest/System/Messages" endpoint begins returning messages for button/agent state changes allowing me to tabulate "agents avail/unavail per skill", "total chats queued per button", "new chats established", and a few others.

Can anyone from Salesforce comment? Is this endpoint hidden for a reason?

(Will update with the endpoint, if anyone from SF gives me the go ahead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, is not possible at the moment as there is no API for this.

Comment: Seems like such a basic feature. Odd this is lacking. Every chat service in the industry has this functionality. :-/